# Rapid growth of a Mailbox Database logs

Tags: exchange-2010

Recently, the Mailbox Database logs of a custumer's Exchange 2010 rapidly grew from nearly 0 GB to 50 GB, fullfilling the corresponding disk. This happened over night with no particular maintenance operation ongoing, in about 3 hours. No user was working at this time.

We had to activate circular logging for the disk space to be freed the next morning, to restore customer's mail flow.

We found nothing in the mail logs that could explain this issue. This is the second time it happened for this particular customer, and we really would like to understand why, all of a sudden, database logs are growing until disk saturation.
In a normal day, database logs would grow from 0 to about 15 GB, until the backup is performed and the logs are flushed.

What would be our options?

Comment: I've voted to move this question over to our enterprise-grade site where this question is going to find a more specifically knowledgeable and experienced audience. Also, you may not have seen anything in the logs that YOU think was part of the issue, but you are the only one here who has seen the logs or has access to them. You'll need to find what IS in those logs and give us a synopsis, adding that information to the question itself.

Comment: The only debug logs that I can think of are Windows Events and Exchange Message tracking. I found nothing relevant in either of these two sources. My question was more : what is the best place for me to find what happened? Is there any other log folder in Exchange that I can use for me investigation?

Comment: I think you could also check if there is any related schedule tasks. And here is a reference about troubleshoot growth logs about Exchange, you could have a look at. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2013/04/18/troubleshooting-rapid-growth-in-databases-and-transaction-log-files-in-exchange-server-2007-and-2010/